# how to use client template for dropdownList in telerik grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I want to create a dropdownList with unique id in telerik grid. This grid is having in-line edit and add. So, I have created a client template which is working fine with view mode. When clicked on in-line edit button of grid, that dropdownList gets converted into a textbox. So, I want to maintain that dropdownList in edit mode as well. Thanks in advance.

Here is my sample code:

```
grid = grid
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(customField => customField.FieldNumber)
                   .Filterable(false)
                   .Sortable(false)
                   .IncludeInContextMenu(false)
                   .ReadOnly()
                   .Width("60px");
            // here is my client template code
            var dropdownListType = @"&nbsp; <select id='ddlTypeId_<#=CustomMenuId#>'>"
               + "<option value='" + Utilities.GetLabels("CustomMenu_List") + "'>" + Utilities.GetLabels("CustomMenu_List") + "</option>"
               + "<option value='" + Utilities.GetLabels("CustomMenu_Textbox") + "'>" + Utilities.GetLabels("CustomMenu_Textbox") + "</option>";

            columns.Bound(customField => customField.Type)
                .ClientTemplate(dropdownListType)
                .Width("30%")
                .Title("Type");
        });
```

Comment: In edit mode, it will reflect with the value from db. But, I want to populate an list with dropdownList.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a demo page for grid. Look here : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom I shared image below it is in edit mode and dropdown style.

[image]

You can set as parameter your model directly  to ClientTemplate method. Look demo for detail pls.

Comment: hello Mehmet, this is working with latest Kendo UI. I am using simple telerik grid. So, some of the functions are not working with simple telerik grid.